# SwapChainPanel performance issues

Tags: c#, performance, uwp, direct2d, sharpdx

I'm using a `SwapChainPanel` to render a control. The render method attaches to the `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event.

Also, `RenderTarget.CreateCompatibleTarget` is called to create an offscreen target. The `compatibleTarget.Bitmap` property is called to create a **cached** bitmap that can be blitted onscreen.

During each frame:

1. `BeginDrawing()` is called on the onscreen target.
2. If the scene has been invalidated by program logic, it is redrawn to the offscreen target.
3. The onscreen target is cleared using the background color. Without this, successive frames are somehow blended into each other.
4. The offscreen bitmap (cached above) is drawn onto the onscreen target using `onscreenTarget.DrawBitmap(cachedBitmap)`, with opacity set to 1.
5. `onScreenTarget.Flush()` is called to flush the contents.
6. `EndDrawing()` is called on the onscreen target.

I find that this gives a very low frame rate.

**Comparison with WindowRenderTarget**

For comparison, I tested the exact same scene code in a WinForms app using a `WindowRenderTarget`. (SharpDX makes this possible since it works on UWP as well as desktop.) This gives a much higher frame rate, and zero steady-state CPU consumption.

**Questions:**

1. Why does `SwapChainPanel` produce such a low frame rate compared to `WindowRenderTarget`?
2. Why is it necessary to clear the onscreen target each frame before drawing the bitmap in step 4 even when the opacity is 1?
3. Can I avoid steps 1-6 if nothing has changed? This consumes around 7% CPU.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think there should be too much performance difference between SwapChainPanel & WindowRenderTarget, because both of them are almost directly based on DirectX components. You could compare their settings to investigate the performance differences: Is the SwapChainPanel related with D2D device? Any differences among the configuration of devicecontext, swapchain description, and WindowRenderTarget's renderTargetProperty; Are there any difference between the bitmap processing methods?
2. THe opacity is set for the image you are drawing. However, the clear() if for the overall rendering view.
3. When you mean "if nothing changed", I supposed you mean you have nothing to draw. Then of course you can do nothing. Otherwise, the step from 1 to 6 are necessary.

Besides, you can find a good documented SwapChainPanel example [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-SwapChainPanel-00cb688b). Some settings in this example are for performance improving.

Comment: 3. By "if nothing changed" I mean that the next frame to draw is identical to the previous frame. The compositor still calls back 60 times a second to draw frames. How can I tell it to use the previously drawn frame? If I do nothing, flicker seems to result.

Comment: Normally when to call render() is controlled by the backend directX functions. Normally it is called to re-render when the app is resumed, or CompositionScaleChanged , or SizeChanged, or device lost. You can refer to the sample code to find out recommended usage model for re-render.